# Laravel Eloquent ORM maximum rows it could retrieve

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with about 35,000 rows, I want to retrieve it and var_dump all the rows but I could not.

Then I limit the number of rows by 2000, that is alright.

What is the problem, is Laravel Eloquent limiting the number of row each time retrieve or is the hardware problem?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the logs?

Comment: nothing in log, and nothing shows in the browser when i return it.

Comment: What about the web server log?

Comment: Post some code too.. :)

Comment: the code are simple, i retrieve all using  User::all() , which should return me 35000 result

Comment: but when i limit it using User::take(2000)->get() , that is alright.

Comment: Probably a limit on your PHP, have a look in your webserver's error log for exceptions..

Comment: actually, i have try it out the maximum rows each time it could retrieve, is about 3000 , or it is depend on the data size

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36731/discussion-between-kent-liau-and-msturdy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion: You're hitting the memory limit on the server...

The solution is either

1. increase the limit there, or
2. find another way to process the users, per 2000 users for example...

the second is more scalable, the question you should ask yourself is

> **"What happens when I have 1000 times the number of users?"**